Hide Android keyboard by default but allow a QR scanner input while hidden
I have a web app where I want to read from the QR scanner on a Honeywell EDA57 terminal (runs Android 12 and latest mobile Chrome) and other similar devices. It works well except when I want to disable the virtual keyboard that pops up, while reading from hardware, which i believe essentially acts like a keyboard.
I would like to:

Disable virtual keyboard popping up automatically
Be able to pull the keyboard if needed for a manual entry.

I've successfully disabled the popup but when I do that QR scanner won't read into the input field.
<input inputmode="text" virtualkeyboardpolicy="manual">

What can I do to achieve this behaviour without preventing the QR scanner from working?
